# SilverStripe : How to get all records using get()

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

A simple question. In my code

A customer has many partners. If I want to get customer details and a customer have how many partners. What I trying to do is,

```
$customer = Customer::get();
return Partners::get()->filter('CustomerID', $customer->ID);
```

Unfortunately above code is not working for me, Is there any easy way to get.?

Answer (score 1):

@Mifas you're still getting the error because $customer = Customer::get() is still returning a DataList rather than a single Customer object, as @Zauberfisch described. Before you call the relationship method you need to be sure you're calling it on an individual Customer.

```
$customer = Customer::get()->first();
// OR, if you're looking up a specific Customer
$customer = Customer::get()->filter('ID', <custID>)->first();
// If you're looking up by ID only, there is a shortcut that still returns one dataobject only:
$customer = Customer::get()->byID( <custID> );
```

In that case, either of the following lines would work (but the relationship 'magic' method @Zauberfisch pointed out is the preferred method)

```
$partners = $customer->Partners();
// OR
$partners = Partner::get()->filter('CustomerID', $customer->ID);
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I modified my code to `$customer = Customer::get(); return HostingContract::get()->filter('CustomerID',$customer->ID);` So how am I now get the records. ?

Comment: You need to add ->first() to Customer::get() or you're still getting a DataList not a DataObject.

Comment: ah,, no no,, What I want is, I need to get all customer records and number of partners they got.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a has_many relationship between Customers and Partners you should simply be able to get all the customers with Customer::get(); and introspect using the ORM.

Then you have 2 options for accessing how many partners they have.

1) Use the ORM! Assuming your relationship is named "Partners". In your PHP when you loop through Customer::get() you can access "->Partners()->Count();" for each record.

```
foreach(Customer::get() as $customer){
   echo $customer->Partners()->Count();
}
```

2) Or if you just need this in your template as Zauberfisch mentions you can do a template loop thorugh your customers and access the count of Partners using the dot notation.

```
<% loop Customers %>
     $Partners.Count
<% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 0):

the first problem is that you need to understand how `::get()` works.
`::get()` returns a DataList object, even if it only finds 1 item, its still a list with the DataObject inside, so you need to get the DataObject.

If you are sure it contains only 1 item, then you can simply do `$customer Customer::get()->First()`.
But in your case I am pretty sure that `Customer::get()` will contain ALL customers.

so its more like `$customers = Customer::get();`

getting the single customer that you want depends on your code.

---

now on to your actual question:

```
return Partners::get()->filter('CustomerID', $customer->ID);
```

is actually correct, this would work. but there is a better way to do this.
SilverStripe creates 'magic' methods for the relations (has_one, has_many and many_many).
so if Customer has_many Partners, then:

```
$partners = $customer->Partners();
```

or in template:

```
<% loop $Partners %> ... <% end_if %>
```

read more about the SilverStripe datamodel here: 
http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/topics/datamodel

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now its clear, This is my code, `$customer = Customer::get();return $customer->Partners();` Now im getting an error?